# Certificate generation by ACM for Cloud front in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager

I have a question related to Cloud Front.
If I have CF enabled with s3 origin in `Account A`, and then I  create a Route 53 DNS records in `Account B`  and point to the CF.
I will need to add `alternate domain name` in CF which in `Account A`  and a  certificate as well. Will ACM generate a certificate in the `Account A` when DNS entry `hello.example.com` is in another account ?

Comment: Yes, ACM can do that and you need to configure a hosted zone for your sub-domain (in account B) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ACM will be happy to generate any certificate you ask it to, but to verify the certificate to complete the creation process you will have to create a DNS entry in whatever DNS service you are using. You don't even need to be using Amazon's Route53 DNS service, you can use ACM with any DNS service.

Answer (score 0):

ou can do the following steps
Create ACM in us-east-1 region of Account A.
Once step 1 is done, you will copy the CNAME record of that ACM and go to Account B to create the DNS record for that CNAME values and use DNS validation. Please keep in mind, e.g hello.example.com is your public domain and hosted in Route53.
Back to account A and wait a few seconds, then you will see the status of ACM is issued and you can attach that ACM to your CF in Account A.